# How to sum under certain conditions in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a formula in Excel that I'm trying to work out. The formula is meant to return a sum under certain conditions.

If the salary is less than the limit amount and is greater than 30 hours worked, it is meant to sum the cells. If false then it is meant to return a calculation, but this needs to return by minus itself from a sum total to get to a final result.

The below formula only returns the reduced rate not the `sum total - reduced rate = final` result:

```
=IF($G$7*52<$K$5*(AND($C$4>30)),SUM($K$7:$K$9),($G$7*52)-$K$5)*$K$6
```

I can't seem to manage to think how to return sum total is their a formula I can use that could involve this part of the formula:

```
($G$7*52)-$K$5)*$K$6
```

Comment: You are using AND() incorrectly: `=IF(AND($G$7*52<$K$5,$C$4>30),...`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
=IF($G$7*52<$K$5*(AND($C$4>30)),SUM($K$7:$K$9),SUM($K$7:$K$9)-(($G$7*52)-$K$5)*$K$6)
```